# What does a Doctoral program mean: MS, PhD or both?

Tags: phd, masters

If I understand it right, Graduate school means MS, PhD, or both, but a
Doctoral program means just PhD. Is this correct?

Comment: Graduate school doesn't only point to MS, it points to masters in general, such as M.Tech, M.E., etc.

Answer (score 4):

In general, a Doctoral program ends in a Ph.D ("doctor of philosophy"). If the program does not grant doctorate degrees, it cannot be doctoral. However, a doctoral program may end in a master's degree. For instance, if I chose not to finish my doctoral program, I could instead get a master's degree on the basis of the coursework and research I've done so far.

Comment: And even if you do go through to the PhD, you usually were awarded a master's degree at some point along the way (e.g. after passing prelims successfully).

Comment: @JonCuster Sort of, I think. My understanding is that I'd be wrong to style myself as "First Lastname, M.S." unless I first applied for and was granted the degree, even though I've completed the requirements.

Comment: Mine showed up on my transcript after passing prelims (that was some time ago). On transcripts I review these days during hiring decisions I see it all the time - after the course work and prelims, you get a master's awarded. So, I consider it pretty common. You should check your transcript! (Although I never styled myself with a master's - that wasn't what I was going for).

Comment: So then nobody applies to a doctorate program with the intent of getting an MS, correct?

Comment: @Jamie Well, strictly speaking you should apply to a master's program to get a master's. I would bet that plenty of people do go to doctoral programs not intending to finish, but they're being a bit deceptive in this.

Comment: @JonCuster 'Usually' is, I think, too strong. Some places you do, some places you don't.

Comment: @JessicaB is right. In Europe, for example, Masters and Doctorates are separate things.

Comment: @JessicaB - true, I was neglecting the difference between US and Europe. Here in the US it is nearly universal (coming from having reviewed many many CVs and transcripts over the last decade plus of hiring). My Europe experience was merely helping make PhDs.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that "graduate" study is the broader term. As I understand it, "doctoral" study leads to an academic doctorate, such as a PhD or an EdD -- not to a doctorate of professional practice such as an MD or JD.